# Periodic solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

let be the ODE $ -y''(x)+f(x)y(x)=0 $

if the function $ f(x+T)=f(x) $ is PERIODIC does it mean that the ODE has only periodic solutions ?

if all the solutions are periodic , then can all be determined by Fourier series ??

Comment: Have a look at [Floquet theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. But in in special cases it has at least one periodic solution. The equation is known as [Hill's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_differential_equation), and the theory of its solutions, whether periodic or not, is known as [Floquet theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory). The referenced wikipedia page deals with first order systems; you'll have to rewrite your second order equation to a first order system to use the theory directly.

If you want to learn more, the little book *Hill's equation* by Magnus and Winkler (in the Dover series) is an excellent resource.

Answer (score 6):

No, it doesn't mean that. For instance, $f(x)=0$ is periodic with any period, but $y''(x)=0$ has non-periodic solutions $y(x)=ax+b$.